# How to create a column on a SQL table, based on values of another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I currently have 2 SQL tables:  `table1` and `table2`. `table1` has 2 columns called `id_a` and `column_a`. `table2` has 2 columns called `id_b` and `column_b`.

I would like to create a `new_column` in `table1`. The value of `new_column` should be 1 if the value of `table1.id_a` exists in `table2.id_b`. Otherwise, `new_column` should have the value of 0.

How do I do this? I'm using SQLite3 and `table1` is significantly larger than `table2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple `IN`?

```
SELECT *,
       id_a IN (SELECT id_b FROM table2) AS flag
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple `exists`?

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id_b = t1.id_a)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from table1 t1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `left join` solution for fun! In certain circumstances might even be more efficient than correlated subquery as well.

```
select
    t1.*,
    case 
        when t2.id_b is null then 0
        else 1
    end as new_column
from
    table1 t1
left join
    table2 t2
    on t2.id_b = t1.id_a
```

Comment: Thank you! Why would using `left join` be more efficient than a simple `exist` in subquery?

Comment: No problemo! It depends entirely on the optimizer's decision, it will in fact sometimes rewrite subqueries as a join. The perf boost has to do with the cardinality of the table. Whereby the correlated subquery is performed once for each row of the table. As you can imagine, as the table grows, so does the horsepower required to execute the query.

Comment: And if my `table1` is much larger than `table2`, does the simple `exists` subquery approach execute faster?

Comment: If `table1` is much larger than I would stick to the join approach. If the table is small enough, the optimizer will more than likely elect to do a table scan (this is one of the few situations where scan is "ok"). Reading the record set into memory **once** for the out record set. Far more performant than loading the inner record once for every record in the outer record set. Make sense?

Comment: In many respects, I avoid subqueries at all costs. Unless there truly isn't another option, or it is the more performant in a particular situation. To me, it also somewhat violates the notion of thinking purely in sets. Which is where the true power of an RDMS lies.

Comment: @puifais The SQLite query optimizer will never reqrite a subquery as a join. But with rows computed on demand and with subqueries being implemented as coroutines, joins might execute similar to a correlated subquery.

Comment: You can't say that as if it's an absolute bc it's not certain to do that. It's a cost based optimization. This, your are correct in the circumstances where s join costs less. But this won't always be true.